# Tensorflow - tf.Layers : Error with the function .fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I'm running the example cnn_mnist given on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py) that is using layers module.
I can run the program but a Warning appears telling me that one of the function is deprecated.
I couldn't find which new function needs to be used.

`WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-14-ee49e8b76469>:25: calling BaseEstimator.fit (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.estimator) with batch_size is deprecated and will be removed after 2016-12-01.
Instructions for updating:
Estimator is decoupled from Scikit Learn interface by moving into
separate class SKCompat. Arguments x, y and batch_size are only
available in the SKCompat class, Estimator will only accept input_fn.
Example conversion:
  est = Estimator(...) -> est = SKCompat(Estimator(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to modify that script like this:

```
# Create the Estimator
mnist_classifier = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(
  model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model"))
```

However, please open a Github issue to update that sample so it doesn't mislead anyone else.